# How to call the Gridview Activity from another activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-gridview

I need an idea on how to call an activity that has a gridview from another activity. Basically, supposed my main activity has one button and when you click the button you are directed to another activity with the following sample code

```
 public void onClick(View v){
 if (v.getId() == R.id.button2) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
        this.startActivity(intent);

    }
 }
```

But what if the activity that I'm being redirected to contains a gridview layout, how do I call that when I press the button? I don't have time to write my code here. It would be best if you just give me an idea or make a sample code thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work on any Activity you have regardless of the layout they have. Just replace `Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);`
with `Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivitywithGridView.class);`

Remeber that you cannot see a GridView if it is not populated with data.

Comment: I find it hard implementing that. I tried many tutorials about Gridview and they each have two java class that is being implemented the other being extended to BaseAdapter and the other one for Gridview to call the java class with the extended BaseAdapter. I applied the latter in the Intent code such as you mentioned but it didn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `ActivityName.this` instead of `this`.

Instead of using `this` you could use `ActivityName.this`, it gets you the context of the `Activity`. Currently `this` is giving you `onClick()` method context reference.

Issue is Proper context is not passing so its not starting Activity.

You can try this code.

```
public void onClick(View v){
 if (v.getId() == R.id.button2) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityName.this, GridViewActivity.class);
        ActivityName.this.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: is the ActivityName a keyword or just a variable?

Comment: what is name of Activity?

Comment: nevermind I get your point I think something is wrong with my Gridview java class and the other one that is being extended to BaseAdapter...Thanks for trying to help I think I'll make another thread.

Comment: my apologies but it didn't went well. I'll create another thread along with my codes.

Comment: here is my new thread which I just updated. I included my codes  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33053328/gridview-activity-cannot-be-call-from-another-activity