# Gridview activity cannot be call from another activity

Tags: android, android-gridview

This is an update from my previous questions [How to call the Gridview Activity from another activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33050043/how-to-call-the-gridview-activity-from-another-activity/33050233?noredirect=1#comment53923624_33050233) which I added my codes

Here is my gallery.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/gridview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:columnWidth="90dp"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:gravity="center"
/>
```

Gallery.java

```
 package com.example.diaz.chmscadvertisement;


 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.widget.GridView;

 public class Gallery extends Activity {
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gallery);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
 }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

ImageAdapter.java

```
 package com.example.diaz.chmscadvertisement;

 import android.content.Context;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
 import android.widget.GridView;
 import android.widget.ImageView;

 /**
  * Created by diaz on 10/10/2015.
  */
      public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
     private Context mContext;

     public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
         mContext = c;
     }

     public int getCount() {
         return mThumbIds.length;
     }

     public Object getItem(int position) {
         return null;
     }

     public long getItemId(int position) {
         return 0;
     }

     // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}

// references to our images
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.sample2, R.drawable.sample3,
        R.drawable.sample4, R.drawable.sample5,
        R.drawable.sample6, R.drawable.sample7,
        R.drawable.sample10, R.drawable.sample1,
        R.drawable.sample8, R.drawable.sample9,

};
 }
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.diaz.chmscadvertisement" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logoalijis"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity android:name=".ViewFlipperBody" />
        <activity android:name=".AboutChmsc" />
        <activity android:name=".CampusLife" />
        <activity android:name=".AboutUs" />
        <activity android:name=".MainMenu"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Gallery"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:label="CHMSC-Alijis" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My Main Menu this is where I press the button in order to open the Gridview

MainMenu.java

```
package com.example.diaz.chmscadvertisement;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainMenu extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button button2;
Button button3;
Button button4;
Button button6;
Button button7;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainmenu);

        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        button6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
        button7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);

        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        button3.setOnClickListener(this);
        button4.setOnClickListener(this);
        button6.setOnClickListener(this);
        button7.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void onClick(View v){
        if (v.getId() == R.id.button2) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ViewFlipperBody.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);

        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.button3) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, AboutChmsc.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);

        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.button4) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, CampusLife.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
        }

        else if (v.getId() == R.id.button6) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Gallery.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
        }

        else if (v.getId() == R.id.button7) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, AboutUs.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
}
```

The problem is that when I click the Gallery button(which is the button6 in my MainMenu.java) the gallery.xml is not opening at all. If I replace mThumbIds's element with R.drawable.icon_launcher,it will work properly.Any idea? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should add a layout to wrap GridView in gallery.xml,otherwise its width and height will be 0dp.

Comment: You mean something like  <LinearLayout> <GridView> </Gridview> </LinearLayout>?

Comment: Yes,add a parent layout for gridview,if you add the xml as the activity's layout,you can add merge to optimize it.

Comment: can you please  give me an example I'm new to android.

Comment: Please see my another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your Gridview will not show up if the images are not available. Please try the same code by using ic_launcher in place of sample images.

Comment: it won't work because if I press the button6 where it will direct me to the Gallery activity nothing happens besides I those sample images are already inside the res->.drawable directory. But if this is all you can do think I'll try your suggestion later. Thanks

Comment: your suggestion did work. It opened my Gallery activity. Do you have any idea how those sample images didnt work out? I'm pretty sure that they are inside the drawable

Comment: If you are still stuck here.. please give me your sample images

Comment: are you referring to my actual images if so I'm sorry I don't know how to post the images here in stockoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <GridView 
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"/>
</merge>
```

Comment: your suggestion didn't work. As Sukvhir suggested above it already did show up the ic_launcher meaning that the problem must be my image. Could it be the resolution size?

Comment: I've got a new problem following Sukvhir's suggestion I concluded that it has something to do with my resolution of the image that I'm calling because they mostly range from 700x500 resolution size so I decided to change their size to around 50x50 using any Image Editor such as photoshop but the size seems to be the same as when the ic_launcher was drawn so I change it again this time to aroun 250x250 but then again it shows the same size as the ic_launcher. Do you have any idea how did this happen?

Comment: I think that's because your item view is just a imageview,no parent layout wraps it,so its size won't work.

Comment: Are you referring to my gallery.xml? Would you mind giving me an example? I don't have time to include this on my project now since I'm looking for another way but I'd be happy to learn something from this if this has been solve